# toggle function is not being called when i click the button using onclick function in javascript

Tags: javascript

const toggleBtn = document.getElementById('btn');

setInterval(displayTime,1000);

```
toggleBtn.onclick= toggle() 
{
    if (toggleBtn.innerHTML=="Light") {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor ="white";
        document.getElementById('hours').style.color = 'black';
        document.getElementById('minutes').style.color = 'black';
        document.getElementById('seconds').style.color = 'black';
        document.getElementById('session').style.color = 'black';
        toggleBtn.innerHTML ="Dark";
        toggleBtn.style.color ="white";
        toggleBtn.style.backgroundColor ="black";
    } else {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor ="black";
        document.getElementById('hours').style.color = 'white';
        document.getElementById('minutes').style.color = 'white';
        document.getElementById('seconds').style.color = 'white';
        document.getElementById('session').style.color = 'white';
        toggleBtn.innerHTML ="Light";
        toggleBtn.style.color ="black";
        toggleBtn.style.backgroundColor ="white";
    }
};
```

function displayTime(){};

how am i supposed to make this work? Earlier i tried using addEventListener('click', toggle) instead of onclick but that also didn't work.
I want the timer to keep running but the toggle function to work only when i click the button specified by the id "btn".

Comment: Surely there's an error in your console. Your syntax here is invalid. `toggle()` should either be an anonymous function, or define it elsewhere and call it here like you describe `addEventListener("click",toggle)`. Please include what you did try with `addEventListener()` and why it didn't work.

Comment: resolved it using `addEventListener()`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
toggleBtn.onclick = function() {
    if (toggleBtn.innerHTML=="Light") {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor ="white";
        document.getElementById('hours').style.color = 'black';
        document.getElementById('minutes').style.color = 'black';
        document.getElementById('seconds').style.color = 'black';
        document.getElementById('session').style.color = 'black';
        toggleBtn.innerHTML ="Dark";
        toggleBtn.style.color ="white";
        toggleBtn.style.backgroundColor ="black";
    } else {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor ="black";
        document.getElementById('hours').style.color = 'white';
        document.getElementById('minutes').style.color = 'white';
        document.getElementById('seconds').style.color = 'white';
        document.getElementById('session').style.color = 'white';
        toggleBtn.innerHTML ="Light";
        toggleBtn.style.color ="black";
        toggleBtn.style.backgroundColor ="white";
    }
};
```

Comment: no that didn't make any difference